# CCAvenue Sandbox Site For Testing

Tags: php, sandbox, ccavenue

I want to integrate CCAvenue payment gateway in my site. Is there any sandbox site available for CCAvenue to test payments? If any provide me the link.

Comment: Is there a way to test ccavenue from my local machine? Always a 112 error. Please help

Answer (score 23, accepted):

CCAvenue removed the PDF from their website so I removed the official link.

Removed broken links. I found another copy but at this point it might be outdated.
https://docplayer.net/12395510-Ccavenue-world-integration-manual-version-1-0.html

Check this manual , it might be what are you looking for.
There is something about testing the integration on page 19.

I found  another one which seems to be a more recent copy with a more up to date explanation. 
https://jemds.com/data_pdf/1_CCAvenue%20Integration%20-%20Ver%202.0.pdf

Comment: The link is dead

Comment: This link is redirect to CCAvenue home page

Comment: Links have been update. Hope this helps. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 13):

From my experience, this is not a great app for sandboxing.  If you download the manual (linked by @rgerculy you should see the information for integration.  However, here is what must happen:

First, login to the merchant account and go to the integration section and download the sample code.  There you'll see some PHP test code.  You can probably save time by working this into your application.

Next, make sure to activate your remote merchant processing.  By default, its deactivated.

Finally, it looks like you can use 4111-1111-1111-1111 to simulate a failure.  To simulate success, you must use a real card for testing - less than $1USD - and put the term SUB-MERCHANT TEST in the extra notes text area.

There doesn't seem to be an easier way to do this, that I'm aware of. :(

Answer (score 8):

To test your transaction on CCAvenue. Here is the step given by CCAvenue.

**This section for all Clients. Now you're ready to test your account by doing Live transactions! Please keep in mind that you cannot test CCAvenue by using American Express or JCB credit card and also any of the Net Banking interfaces. Please use Mastercard, Visa, Diners Club or a Citibank eCard to do a test transaction. Also remember that while placing test orders, always put the words "SUB MERCHANT TEST" in the Instructions text box. After the transaction is successful, please log in to your CCAvenue account using your client ID and Password and cancel the test transaction. Please do not capture the transaction as this would constitute a "cash advance" against one's own cards, which our credit card companies and the payment gateways do not allow on the Internet.**

Answer (score 7):

**Current Process:**

Step one is to register in CCAvenue, and your account will be activated much sooner. And once your account is activated you will receive,

1. Merchant ID.
2. Link to activate your account and setup password for your CCAvenue account.

at your registered email address.

Once you activate your account and set up the password for your account, you can get the working key and access code in the dashboard.

To test your code, you can use `https://test.ccavenue.com` as form URL to CCAvenue website. All the transactions to this test URL will not be processed.

If you need to test your code from your local machine, you should write to CCAvenue service desk at service@ccavenue.com with your merchant ID and localhost URL to white-list. Else CCAvenue will throw error "Merchant Authentication Failed".

Hope this might help someone who is looking for a testing environment.

Comment: Works Perfectly

Comment: test.ccavenue.com will work only when you encrypt your request parameters properly. The URL test.ccavenue.com will throw 404 error when you try with no parameters.

Answer (score 2):

For testing ccavenue you have to mail your merchant id and register site to ccavenue help team and they will activate your account for test environment

Answer (score 0):

By default: test account is not active in ccavenue. But the live payment gateway is active. You need to mail salessupport@ccavenue.com with merchant_id and domain names to be whitelisted. It will be activated in 24 hours.